# python threading for nested loops

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, loops, nested

I have written a program that works reasonably well, however, I am pretty sure there is a way to speed it up.

Initially, I wrote it without the threading set up from below (although that said, I have a feeling that the threading set up below is having no effect at all).

I will say up front, I am totally new to threading, processing or any performance improvements to my code.

I was hoping that someone could run their eye over the below snippet and see if there was a way that I could implement something to run parallel threads/processes etc. (in summary to speed it up or at least process more files at once)

I also am having troubles trying to get any other performance speed ups to work with the nested for loop below:

```
for file in files:
    for IPAddress in IPAddresses:
```

- files - is a list of (gzipped) files
- IPAddresses - is a list of IP Addresses

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = [
        'file1',
        'file2',
        'file3'
    ]

    IPAddresses = [
        '1.1.1.1',
        '1.1.1.2',
        '1.1.1.3'
    ]

    threads = []
    for file in files:
        for IPAddress in IPAddresses:
            t = threading.Thread(target=Search_files(file, IPAddress))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
            print('file: ' + file + ' processed for IP Address: ' + IPAddress.upper() + '\n')

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example how to use `multiprocessing.Pool` alongside with `itertools.product`:

```py
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
from itertools import product


files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

IPAddresses = ["1.1.1.1", "1.1.1.2", "1.1.1.3"]


def my_func(tpl):
    f, ip = tpl
    sleep(1)
    return f"Done {f}-{ip}!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        for res in p.imap_unordered(my_func, product(files, IPAddresses)):
            print(res)
```

Prints the results as they come in (unordered), all CPU cores should be utilized:

```
Done file1-1.1.1.1!
Done file1-1.1.1.2!
Done file3-1.1.1.2!
Done file2-1.1.1.3!
Done file2-1.1.1.2!
Done file2-1.1.1.1!
Done file1-1.1.1.3!
Done file3-1.1.1.3!
Done file3-1.1.1.1!
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej for getting back to me. As soon as I get a chance tomorrow, I'll give it a go, thanks. Sorry, won't get a chance for a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej, I'm finally checking this out now. Still a bit stuck on how exactly to change my program to get this to work and I kind of understand what you wrote above, but think I need to spend more time on it. For example the tpl is a tuple I am guessing, so am I meant to change my function from:
Search_file(file, IPAddress) to a tuple? Sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej, I thought it was going to be a massive job to modify, but I think it's worked out quite well, thank you so much.

To be honest, I'm still getting a strange anomaly where it doesn't appear to iterate through each of the IP's in the files, but will keep at it.